# Theorems & Proof Corrections [discrete mathematics]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, recreational-mathematics

So I've recently started a new chapter in my discrete mathematics course on proof methods. I have come across this problem in my textbook but I'm having a very hard time understanding where to start and what to look for. In all honesty, all the proofs for the theorems look correct to me.

> Each of the  following theorems is either valid or invalid, but the
>   proof given is incorrect even if the theorem is valid. Explain briefly
>   what mistake was made in each case:
>
> 1. **Theorem:** Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be three functions from $\mathbf{N}$ into $\mathbf{R}^+$. If $f \in O(g)$ and $g \in O(h)$,
>      then $f \in O(h)$.
>
>    **Proof:** Consider three unspecified functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ $\mathbf{N}$ into $\mathbf{R}^+$. Assume that $f \in O(g)$ and $g \in O(h)$. Since $f \in O(g)$, there is a real number $c$ and a positive
>      integer $n_0$ such that for every $n \ge  n_0$, $f(n) \le cg(n)$.
>      Similarly, for every  $n \ge n_0$, $g(n)  \le ch(n)$. Therefore, for
>      every $n  \ge n_0$, $f(n) \le cg(n) \le c(ch(n)) =  c^2 h(n)$. Hence
>      $f \in O(h)$ using the constants $c^2$ and $n_0$.
> 2. **Theorem:** If $n^2 + n - 6 \ge 0$, then $n \ge 2$.
>
>    **Proof:** When $n \ge 2$, we know that $n^2 \ge 4$, so $n^2 + n \ge 6$, and therefore $n^2 + n - 6 \ge 0$.
> 3. **Theorem:** No matter how we choose an integer $n$, the value $n^3 + n$ will be even.
>
>    **Proof:** We use  a proof by contradiction. Assume that  the theorem is false. That is, $n^3 + n$ is odd. This is  not true, as
>      we can see by choosing $n = 2$ ($2^3 +  2 = 10$,  which is even). So
>      we have found  a contradiction, which  means the theorem is true.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is $O(g)$?

Comment: For Theorem 2, check out what happens when $n = -100.$  You'll see (I think) that this is a counterexample to the theorem.  What happens when you apply the supposed proof to this counterexample?  Does that help you see why it's not actually a proof?

Comment: For the second theorem, you're only proving that every $n\geq 2$ satisfies $n^2+n-6\geq 0$ but not in the other direction...

Comment: For the third theorem, the assumption to be disproved should be *$n^3+n$ isn't always even* instead of '$n^3+n$ is odd'...

Answer (score 0):

Apply the proof of theorem 1 to the particular functions $f(n) = 2, g(n) = n, h(n) = \frac {n^2}{16}$. Find the best $n_0$ and $c$ to show $f \in O(g)$, and then check that against the final line of the proof.

For 2, the theorem is $n^2 + n - 6 \ge 0 \implies n \ge 2$. That is, from $n^2 + n - 6 \ge 0$, you can prove that $n \ge 2$. Is that what their "proof" does?

For 3, here is a very similar proof:

**Theorem** for all $n$, $n$ is odd.

**Proof:** Suppose not, then $n$ is even, but that is false, because when $n = 1$, $n$ is not even. A contradiction, so the theorem is true.

Can you spot the error in this version?